# Listing locations in Azure using Python Azure SDK error

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure

I am trying out the listing of different locations in Azure using Python Azure SDKs from Windows machine
Below is the error :

[image]

Please see my code :

```
import os
import sys
import logging
from azure import *
from azure.servicemanagement import *


subscription_id = 'XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
certificate_path = '\.pem'

   sms = ServiceManagementService(subscription_id, certificate_path)
   result = sms.list_subscriptions()
   for location in result:
    print(location.name)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I hope this helps, you can use the new api to list locations, you don't need to use a certificate :).

```
    from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
    from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient


    subscription_id = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
    client_id = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
    secret = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
    tenant_id = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"

    creds = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=secret,                 
    tenant=tenant_id)

    subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(creds)
    locations = subscription_client.subscriptions.list_locations(subscription_id)
    for location in locations:
        print(location.name)
```

generating client ID and secret can be done by running the cli command:

```
    az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth > my.azureauth
```

Comment: This no longer seems to work:`ImportError: No module named mgmt.subscription` even if azure-mgmt-subscription is included. Apparently, it's moved [somewhere else](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-resource/azure/mgmt/resource/subscriptions/subscription_client.py), but can't find exactly where...

Comment: pip3 install azure-common + pip3 install azure-mgmt-subscription, was enough for me to get it to work. maybe try pip3 install azure ?

Answer (score 2):

According to your code & the error information, I think the issue was caused by the value of the `certificate_path` variable which is not a valid file path. On Windows, the path `\` means the root path of disk driver like `C:\` or `D:\`, and the file name `.pem` just is a file suffix name, not a valid file name, and the symbol `\` is not a valid character for naming file. So please use a valid file path of a existing valid certificate file in your code.

Meanwhile, the list locations functions in ASM mode are different from its in ARM mode. The ASM one lists all of the data center locations that are valid for the specified subscription, but the ARM one list all of the available geo-locations. Please see the related REST API references below to know them because of Azure SDK for Python only wrapped the REST APIs.

1. List locations in ASM mode, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg441293.aspx.
2. List locations in ARM mode, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions#Subscriptions_ListLocations.

Comment: @ Peter, Yes i am using the windows and i am following the complete path to the .pem key file

Comment: @ Peter, I have tried with the creation of Openssl certifcates using "openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem" for PEM key creation and "openssl x509 -inform pem -in mycert.pem -outform der -out mycert.cer" for Certificate creation

Comment: @ Peter, and uploaded the .cert to Azure Classic portal. But still not able to access the servicemanagement APis of Azure.

Comment: Link for the ARM mode is broken :(

Comment: @Vini.g.fer Indeed. Please search `List all of the available geo-locations` to access the [Bing cached page](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?d=4945699395799061&w=zLWiwnirFYfJCy9ZBtK_C9F5CyPs6FbQ) for the link  temporarily.

Comment: @Vini.g.fer I have update the link in the above content. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Based on the stacktrace, it's seems your certificate is not valid. This might help you:
http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servicemanagement.html#creating-and-uploading-new-certificate-with-openssl

It's not directly related to your question, but this method is part of the Service Management library of Azure. Current recommendation is to use the Azure Resource Management library (a.k.a. ARM):

- Install the ARM client for Python:
  http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#installation
- Create a resource client:
  http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resourcemanagement.html
- The list_location method:
  http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.operations.html#azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.operations.SubscriptionsOperations.list_locations

Comment: @ Laurent , I have tried with the creation of Openssl certifcates using "openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem" for PEM key creation and "openssl x509 -inform pem -in mycert.pem -outform der -out mycert.cer" for Certificate creation

Answer (score 1):

An update to the answer by `@darc`. Azure SDK for python has changed the way how auth works from `from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials` to `from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential`. The newer version has been re-designed and replaced by `azure-identity`.
Use the code below to refer to things that have changed from `@darc`'s answer

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient

subscription_id = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
client_id = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
secret = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
tenant_id = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"

creds = ClientSecretCredential(client_id=client_id, client_secret=secret,tenant_id=tenant_id)
subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(creds)

locations = subscription_client.subscriptions.list_locations(subscription_id)
for location in locations:
    print(location.name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `sms.list_locations()` to list out the regions.

Thanks,
Gopal.