# Querying available locations in Azure SDK for node

Tags: node.js, azure

I would like to list the locations available for a particular subscription, pretty much in the same way that it's done with `az account list-locations` from the command line, or like [it's listed here for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494727/listing-locations-in-azure-using-python-azure-sdk-error)
However, I can't find a straighforward way to do that. The [example here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/8691046c2ca738552d815f6967f5f54b04840276/examples/ARM/compute/vm-sample.js) apparently creates a virtual machine, but is not too well documented.
I can't even get past the initial step of providing credentials to use my account ([this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/computeManagement/README.md) could be it, but it's geared towards working with compute service; I don't know how it can be translated into simple management).
Is there any step-by-step tutorial I have missed?
The [azure-mgmt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-mgmt) package seems clear enough, but it seems also a bit outdated and it's not clear if it's current anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need this to auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/javascript/api/azure-arm-resource/subscriptionclient?view=azure-node-latest

and this call to get locations: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/javascript/api/azure-arm-resource/locationlistresult?view=azure-node-latest

Node SDK repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node

Comment: I was rather looking for an example, if possible. Still not clear, from the reference, what needs to be done.

Comment: yeah, i'm not a node expert, unfortunately. looks like you can borrow from here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/examples/ARM/compute/vm-sample.js#L206